# How to 'select' an item in an array of JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following script for an Angular controller, to populate a dropdown with month names:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
function Calculator($scope) {

    $scope.yearArray = [];
    $scope.monthArray = [
        { index: 1, name: "January" },
        { index: 2, name: "February" },
        { index: 3, name: "March" },
        { index: 4, name: "April" },
        { index: 5, name: "May" },
        { index: 6, name: "June" },
        { index: 7, name: "July" },
        { index: 8, name: "August" },
        { index: 9, name: "September" },
        { index: 10, name: "October" },
        { index: 11, name: "November" },
        { index: 12, name: "December" }
    ];

    for (var y = currentYear; y < currentYear + 10; y++) {
        $scope.yearArray.push(y);
    }

    //$scope.startMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    $scope.startYear = currentYear;
}
```

Then the following elements:

```
<select data-ng-options="month.name for month in monthArray" data-ng-model="startMonth" id="dateMonth" style="height: 40px; width: 100%;"></select>
<label data-ng-bind="startMonth.index"></label>
<select data-ng-options="year for year in yearArray" data-ng-model="startYear" id="dateYear" style="height: 40px; width: 100%;"></select>
<label data-ng-bind="startYear"></label>
```

How can I set `$scope.startMonth` to the current month, within my array of months? I am only interest in the `index` of the month, for use in calculations, but I do want the select to show the correct name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy

try this code

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
function Calculator($scope) {

    $scope.yearArray = [];
    $scope.monthArray = [
        { index: 1, name: "January" },
        { index: 2, name: "February" },
        { index: 3, name: "March" },
        { index: 4, name: "April" },
        { index: 5, name: "May" },
        { index: 6, name: "June" },
        { index: 7, name: "July" },
        { index: 8, name: "August" },
        { index: 9, name: "September" },
        { index: 10, name: "October" },
        { index: 11, name: "November" },
        { index: 12, name: "December" }
    ];

    for (var y = currentYear; y < currentYear + 10; y++) {
        $scope.yearArray.push(y);
    }
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth();
    $scope.startMonth = $scope.monthArray[n-1];
    $scope.startYear = currentYear;
}
```

The changes are here only

```
       var d = new Date();// current date
        var n = d.getMonth();// current month (result 1 or 2 or 3....)
        $scope.startMonth = $scope.monthArray[n-1];
```

> If this month is 4, then you can subtract one  with the month for get correct index of value. because the array index start with 0,1,2,3...... not by 1,2,3,...... So why i using `[n-1]`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Duh, I've spent too much time using LINQ against C# collections and it's made me stupid to array basics.